# Ошибка при подключении базы данных

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

пытаюсь научится подключать базу данных.
Пытаюсь подключится с помощью этого кода

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");
 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 database: "usersdb",
 password: ""
});
// тестирование подключения
connection.connect(function(err){
   if (err) {
     return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
   }
   else{
     console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
   }
});
// закрытие подключения
connection.end(function(err) {
 if (err) {
   return console.log("Ошибка: " + err.message);
 }
 console.log("Подключение закрыто");
});
```

Сервер запускаю через sql server configuration manager.
После запуска подключается через msql sms, но при подключении через код выдает

````
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Ошибка: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart```
````

Comment: зачем вы подключаетесь к mysql серверу, если у вас ms sql 2019 сервер, судя по вашему комментарию в ответе ниже?

Comment: а как правильно?

Comment: как установить тогда mysql?

Comment: скачиваете в интернете дистрибутив и устанавливаете

Answer (score 0):

ECONNREFUSED происходит когда сервер отказался принимать соединение и закрыл сокет до подтверждения. Нужно проверить настройки firewall и вообще возможность соединиться с MySQLd по TCP. Вполне возможно, что ты вообще не запустил tcp сервер?

Добавлено спустя...

Открываем файл my.ini комментируем в секции mysqld `skip-networking` и выставляем свой порт (по умолчанию 3306)

```
[mysqld]
#skip-networking
port=3306
```

Перезапускаем сервис mysqld, и проверяем любым порт сканером (https://www.advanced-port-scanner.com/ru/help/)

Если работает, то пробуем зайти с сайта, если нет - то проверяем firewall.

Comment: как лучше проверить эти настройки?

Comment: @RomanSladkov - я дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: где должен находится my.ini?

Comment: sql server 2019